# symfony2 best practice for creating a resuable class and function for controller

Tags: php, symfony, twig

i have a method to find all categories as the following

```
public function showAllCategory()
{
    $category = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
        ->findAll();

    return $category;

}
```

the function is in my default controller, the returned object will assign to a template, if the categoryes is required for showing for every pages of my website, how can i avoid to add this function for each controller everytime?

Comment: you can create twig extension and fetch categories from here. [See here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: Use [`render(controller())`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) in Twig.

Comment: Have you considered accepting one of the answers below?

Comment: need time to test, i will, thx

Answer (score 2):

So put your action in a controller that will be used everywhere (such as `MainController` or `SiteController` (I usually use the one where the main `indexAction()` is)).

```
// MainController.php

public function showAllCategory()
{
    $category = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:Category')
                ->findAll();

    return $category;
}
```

And use in your Twig template:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Main:showAllCategory')) }}
```

You will need to have the proper Twig template in `app/Resources/views/Main/showAllCategory.html.twig` (assuming you are using `Symfony2.7`).

Answer (score 0):

As [James Akwuh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4958421/james-akwuh%20James%20Akwuh) said I prefer to use [Twig Extensions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

In my opinion, it can be difficult to anyone who will update the controller, to know that is being called from the views. When is an twig extension, you already know that is some logic used specifically in the view layer.